# Incorrect Output_

Tags: java, output

```
public class FooCorporation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Employee 1:");
        payment(7.5,35);
        System.out.println("Employee 2:");
        payment(8.2, 47);
        System.out.println("Employee 3:");
        payment(10.00,73);
    }

    public static void payment(double basePay, int hours) {
        if(basePay<8. || hours >60) {
            System.out.println("ERORR; base pay less than 8.00$ or hours worked greater than 60.");
    }

        else if(hours<=40) {
                System.out.println("Total pay = " + hours*basePay + "$");
            }
            else if(hours>40) {
                int count = hours-40;
                System.out.println("Total pay = " + (hours-count)*basePay+(1.5*basePay*count)+ "$");

            }
        }
}
```

Why the output is wrong for employee 2?

```
GIVEN : BasePay HoursWorked
Employee 1 $7.50 35 
Employee 2 $8.20 47 
Employee 3 $10.00 73
```

Comment: What is the output you're geting? Ehat do you expect to get?

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: The output is wrong because $ is at the end, end it persists.

Answer (score 0):

When you print here:

```
System.out.println("Total pay = " + (hours-count)*basePay+(1.5*basePay*count)+ "$");
```

You are concatenating the 2 numbers( `(hours-count)*basePay` and `(1.5*basePay*count)` ) and not adding them mathematically. You need to replace it with(enclose the addition of numbers in a bracket):

```
System.out.println("Total pay = " + ((hours - count) * basePay + (1.5 * basePay * count)) + "$");
```

The reason is that first `"Total pay = " + (hours-count)*basePay` is evaluated, and the result of expression `(hours-count)*basePay` is concatenated to the string `Total pay =`. Next the result of this concatenation is concatenated with the result of expression `(1.5 * basePay * count)`. Since you don't want this and you want both the expressions evaluated first before concatenating it, you need to surround them with a bracket so that it takes precedence.

Comment: `8.` is same as `8.0`. Just like `.3` is same as `0.3`. There is no problem here.

Comment: @Pshemo thanks for the tip, I am amazed I never knew about this! Updated my answer.

Comment: You are welcome. For more information visit [JLS - 3.10.2. Floating-Point Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2)

Answer (score 0):

Use 
System.out.println("Total pay = " + ((hours-count)*basePay+(1.5*basePay*count)));

Need to add braces so that JVM knows the order in which the statements need to be processed